# How do big companies effectively store and serve video (over a CDN) - I don't get the math

Tags: amazon-s3, video, google-cloud-storage, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I am building a course hosting website - I want my users to be able to upload videos which their students will stream. This is how I plan to do it but I don't get the math behind this. I'm surely missing something.

1. How do I store the video? - AFAIK rn I can use the cheapest object storage anything like S3, GCP etc. = **$0.005/GB** being the cheapest option.
2. How do I serve those videos? AFAIK rn I can use a CDN that will cache the videos on the edge and serve it to the students = ~ **0.05/GB** being the cheapest option.

Now let's suppose a teacher uploads a 30 min 1080p video that 10000 students will watch.

Size of vid ~ 1.5GB 
Object storage cost = 0.0075

As 10k students will watch it - then data that will go through the CDN = 15000GB

At that 0.05/GB the CDN pricing will be - 15000GB x 0.05/GB = $750

This is unaffordable, obviously, for anyone hosting and serving the video.

There is definitely something that I'm missing here (almost ready to feel dumb after this is solved). Or is this how much it actually costs?

Comment: I want to make sure I understand your use case. You want to live-stream videos to a whole group of students so they would connect at the same time and see the same video (like a live class)? or you would like every student to take their time to watch it at any moment?

Answer (score 0):

That's a little on the expensive size, but it's in the ball park. Using the price calculator at https://mux.com/pricing/ (full disclosure, I work at mux.com) its about half your estimate. Most video of that type is served at a lower quality/bitrate to save on bandwidth (1.5GB for 30 minutes is likely overkill for your type of content). And many business of your type use a third party provider (like mux.com our one of its competitors) who can negotiate better CDN prices due to significantly higher usage patters.

And to answer your originally question. "How do big companies do it". They have a business model that makes it worth while, they negotiate their own peering agreements and/or CDN pricing, and sometimes flat out own the CDN they are using. And very frequently, they operate at a loss.